# pgpool-II configuring multiple masters and slaves

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Actualy I did create a replication system using Pgpool2, with master/slave servers, now i need to add multiple master servers and I need them to be related and updated across each other.

Is it possible to configure multi-master servers using Pgpool2 ?